# How to add hotkey in Python?

Tags: python, keyboard, hotkeys

I'm making a bot for a game and I want to call the function when I press hotkey. I already tried some solutions but it is not good. Here is my code:

```
def start():
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('alt+s'):
            break
        ...

def main():
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('alt+p'):
            start()
```

This way is stable but it causes a lag, it is hard for me to type something.

```
def main():
    keyboard.add_hotkey('alt+p', start, args=(), suppress=True, trigger_on_release=True)
    while True:
        # waiting for the user to press hotkey
        continue
```

As I know keyboard.add_hotkey only returns output so I can't stop the loop in the start function.

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

although this may be late for you, it may help others if they find this...

```
exit = false


def start():
    exit = true


def main():
    keyboard.add_hotkey('alt+p', start, suppress=True, trigger_on_release=True)
    while not exit:
        # put something here, you can't have an empty loop
    keyboard.remove_hotkey('alt+p')
```

When main is called this will add a hotkey that, when triggered, will run the function start. It will then go into the while loop. (note that, unless your are using subprocessing,+ this will stop everything else from going on until you leave the loop) The while loop will run until `exit = false`. It would probably be a good idea to remove the hotkey, although you may have a reason not too.

Comment: The main problem is about start function. If I use `keyboard.is_pressed('alt+s')`, it will be lag because of scan keyboard every time.

Comment: Then don't use keyboard.is_key pressed. Instead use keyboard.add_hotkey with a function linked to it. And in that function change a variable from false to true, when it's true exit the loop.

Answer (score -1):

I found a way to solve my problem that call a function in main thread by hotkey. The idea is use `keyboard.event` to get the press and release key:

```
import keyboard
import time


class Listener:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__listKey = []
        self.__hotkey = {}
        self.__validKey = []

    def start(self):
        while True:
            key = keyboard.read_event()
            if key.name in self.__validKey and key.event_type == 'down':
                if key.name not in self.__listKey:
                    self.__listKey.append(key.name)
                _hotkey = '+'.join(self.__listKey)
                if _hotkey in self.__hotkey:
                    self.__hotkey[_hotkey][0](*self.__hotkey[_hotkey][1])
                else:
                    continue
            else:
                self.__listKey.clear()
                continue

    def addHotKey(self, hotkey, callback, *args):
        self.__hotkey[hotkey] = callback, args
        for _hotkey in hotkey.split('+'):
            self.__validKey.append(_hotkey)


def func():
    while True:
        print('Hello')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if keyboard.is_pressed('alt+s'):
            break


def main():
    lis = Listener()
    lis.addHotKey('alt+b', func)
    lis.start()


main()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details about your code. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).