How to skip dialog printed to terminal when pressing Enter
I have a function that prints the string given to it in a slower way (one letter per 0.05 second):
def tobyTalks(sentence):
    skip = False
    for letter in sentence:
        print('\033[1;34m' + letter + '\033[0m', end='', flush=True)
        if skip:
            time.sleep(0.0001)  # smaller than 0.05s or 0
        else:
            time.sleep(0.05)

Actually it's working and doesn't have any problem, but I want to add an event listener for 'Enter' key press on keyboard to change skip to True.
But sounds like this way is completely wrong and the app doesn't even work.
Could someone please tell me a way to handle this?

You would need a separate thread that accepts input from the console. See threading — Thread-based parallelism.

skip is a local variable; it doesn't matter if another function sets a global skip to True, because tobyTalks ignores it. Get rid of skip = False, and make sure the global variable is intialized before calling tobyTalks.

ok, but how to make an event listener for keyboard keys?

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72221497/how-to-add-hotkey-in-python for how to run code from a hotkey.
